# Textfield background-color white, live grey background-color

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uistoryboard

In my storyboard I have a view controller with textfields.
looks like this:

[image]

white bg-colorif I start my application the textfields bg-color is grey

[image]

looks not good

Why? I have no Swift code which sets the bg-color. Any ideas?

(white bg-color)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your questions that the background color of your textfield is different on runtime.

**Coding Solution:**

```
textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.white //This will change textfield background to white.
```

**Non Coding Solution:**

In storyboard select your textfield and change the background color to the desired color.